# Error inflating image in Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am encountering problem inflating image in collapsing toolbar layout. I have tried compressing images online but none seems to work out for us An image with size equals to 2 mb gets uploaded but different image with size in kbs shows the following error..

[2mb image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l15V4.jpg)

[Image which is in kb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9KuG.png)

mainactivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.admin.myapplication.HajjAndUmrah"
android:background="#fcfcfc">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"


    >
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

        android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
       android:background="@drawable/aprilumrahmin">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class HajjAndUmrah extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hajj_and_umrah);

    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout=(CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsingtoolbar);
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout=(AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {

        boolean isshow= true;
        int scrollRange =-1;
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

            if (scrollRange==-1){

                scrollRange=appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            }
            if (scrollRange+verticalOffset==0){


                collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Hajj and Umrah");
                isshow=true;
            }else if (isshow){

                collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");
                isshow=false;
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

Logcat

```
  --------- beginning of crash
04-21 05:00:56.086 2029-2029/com.example.admin.myapplication 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.admin.myapplication, PID: 2029
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.myapplication/com.example.admin.myapplication.HajjAndUmrah}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.admin.myapplication.HajjAndUmrah.onCreate(HajjAndUmrah.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.admin.myapplication.HajjAndUmrah.onCreate(HajjAndUmrah.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3920012 byte allocation with 3092004 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:115)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:111)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:147)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:143)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.admin.myapplication.HajjAndUmrah.onCreate(HajjAndUmrah.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```